# what is the relationship between a UIView.frame and CALayer.frame? (both pre and post a CATransform3D)

Tags: ios5, uiview, uiimageview, calayer

How is a `CALAyer.frame` related to its `UIView.frame`? (in this case specifically a `UIImageView.frame`).

Given that the values for a `CALayer.frame` potentially differ from its `UIView.frame` following a `CAtransform3D` transformation, do they no longer have any connection?  (and subsequently, should I be more concerned about managing the dimensions of my `CALayer` rather than my `UIImageView` in my superview?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are working with *Core Animation* and layers, you should focus on the following `CALayer` properties:

1. position
2. bounds
3. anchorPoint
4. transform

A quote from Apple Technical Q&A QA1620 available [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1620/_index.html):

> Q:  When I try to animate the frame of a CALayer nothing happens. Why?
>
> A:  The frame property of a CALayer is a derived property, dependent on
> the position, anchorPoint, bounds and transform of the layer. Instead
> of animating the frame, you should instead animate the position or
> bounds, depending on what effect you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Great stuff, thanks - I hadn't seen the Q&A before it looks very helpful